# Difference between two dates in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to calculate  difference between two dates, something like:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('22-NOV-08')-TO_DATE('25-AUG-2008') FROM DUAL;
```

which comes out to be 89 is the `TO_DATE('22-NOV-08')` and `TO_DATE('25-AUG-2008')` included in this 89 days ?

Comment: I think the question is asking if BOTH end dates are part of the total number of days.

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  The subtraction gives you a number of days, not a date range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the difference is in units of days.  Here is a tutorial for [Date Arithmetic](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_date_time.html)

Answer (score 1):

To explain your query

```
SELECT TO_DATE('22-NOV-08')-TO_DATE('25-AUG-2008') FROM DUAL;
```

`TO_DATE('22-NOV-08')` converts the varchar value to date datatype and then what you are doing is nothing but `enddate - startdate` which will return the number of days elapsed.

In case you want the result in

> 1.hours -- multiply the result with 24
>
> 2.Minutes -- multiply the result with 24*60

so on ...

**EDIT:** if your question is; whether the result is inclusive of `enddate` and `startdate`  then the answer is yes and so you have got the result as 89; else you would have got a result of 87 instead.